change multiple div w/javascript
How can I include div 3 and 4 and 5 and 6 and so on ?
I want to overwrite multiple content items with a button / switch
content id 1 and 3 is always visible and changes after clicking / swtich with the buttons


function openOne(oneName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(oneName).style.display = "block";  
}
<div id="1" class="one">
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="2" class="one" style="display:none">
<p>replaced Content 1</p>
<p>replaced Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="3" class="one">
<p>Content 3</p>
<p>Content 4</p>
</div>

<div id="4" class="one" style="display:none">
<p>replaced Content 3</p>
<p>replaced Content 4</p>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="bttn activ" onclick="openOne('1')">Content</button>
  <button class="bttn" onclick="openOne('2')">replaced Content</button>
</div>




Your question isn't clear; what is your specific desired result? What exactly do you wish to overwrite and with what content?

Maybe you should move away from the id  based approach, as this does not scale very well when you want to add further divs.
I based the following snippet on the classes one and two:


const sels=[".one",".two"];
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((btn,i)=>btn.addEventListener("click",swap(i)));

function swap(i){
 return function(ev){
  document.querySelectorAll(sels[i]).forEach(d=>d.style.display="");
  document.querySelectorAll(sels[1-i]).forEach(d=>d.style.display="none");
}}
swap(0)();
<div class="one">
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<div class="two">
<p>replaced Content 1</p>
<p>replaced Content 2</p>
</div>

<div class="one">
<p>Content 3</p>
<p>Content 4</p>
</div>

<div class="two">
<p>replaced Content 3</p>
<p>replaced Content 4</p>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <button>Content</button>
  <button>replaced Content</button>
</div>




It's not entirely clear what you want but my best interpretation is that you want to be able to toggle multiple elements like so:


function openOne(oneName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".one, .two");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var d = (x[i].classList.contains(oneName))?"block":"none";
    x[i].style.display = d;
  }  
}
<div id="1" class="one">
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="2" class="two" style="display:none">
<p>replaced Content 1</p>
<p>replaced Content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="3" class="one">
<p>Content 3</p>
<p>Content 4</p>
</div>

<div id="4" class="two" style="display:none">
<p>replaced Content 3</p>
<p>replaced Content 4</p>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="bttn activ" onclick="openOne('one')">Content</button>
  <button class="bttn" onclick="openOne('two')">replaced Content</button>
</div>



